# How to generalise implementations of 'Seq[String] => Seq[Int]' and 'Iterator[String] => Iterator[Int]' for file processing?

Tags: scala, file, io, iterator

Suppose I've got a function `Seq[String] => Seq[Int]`, e.g. `def len(as: Seq[String]): Int = as.map(_.length)`. Now I would like to apply this function to a text file, e.g. transform *all* the file lines to numbers.

I read a text file as `scala.io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/xxx.txt").getLines` that returns an iterator.
I can use `toList` or `to(LazyList)` to "convert" the iterator to `Seq` but then I read the *whole* file into the memory.

So I need to write another function `Iterator[String] => Iterator[Int]`, which is actually a *copied* version of `Seq[String] => Seq[Int]`. Is it correct ? What is the best way to avoid the duplicated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an *arbitrary* function `Seq[String] => Seq[Int]`, then

> I use toList or to(LazyList) to "convert" the iterator to Seq but in both cases I read the whole file in the memory.

is the best you can do, because the function can start by looking at the end of the `Seq[String]`, or its length, etc.

And Scala doesn't let you look "inside" the function and figure out "it's `map(something)`, I can just do the same `map` for iterators" (there are some caveats with macros, but not really useful here).

> So I need to write another function `Iterator[String] => Iterator[Int]`, which is actually a copied version of `Seq[String] => Seq[Int]`. Is it correct ? What is the best way to avoid the duplicated code?

If you control the definition of the function, you can use higher-kinded types to define a function which works for both cases. E.g. in Scala 2.13

```
def len[C[A] <: IterableOnceOps[A, C, C[A]]](as: C[String]): C[Int] = as.map(_.length)

val x: Seq[Int] = len(Seq("a", "b"))      
val y: Iterator[Int] = len(Iterator("a", "b"))
```